# Recompiling ls command to get wanted colors of a file beginning by README_* , i.e extended with a string

Tags: colors, ls, gnu-coreutils

I make following to this post : [export-ls-colors-apply-the-rule-for-every-file-beginning-by-readme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66636311/export-ls-colors-apply-the-rule-for-every-file-beginning-by-readme)

I summarize the issue briefly:

```
eval `/opt/local/libexec/gnubin/dircolors ~/.dircolors`
export LS_COLORS="${LS_COLORS}*README=00;37;44"
```

Then, when creating a `README` file, then I will get :

[image: README]

But now, I would like to apply the rule and do the same for every filename beginning by README (like `README_something`, `README_important`).

for this, I tried to put:

```
 export LS_COLORS="${LS_COLORS}*README*=00;37;44"
```

but it is not displayed as above image (only white).

### Potential solution

A potential solution would be to recompile `ls` command from `coreutils` sources package (I am on MacOS Big Sur 11.2.3).

The modification is located here :

https://github.com/wertarbyte/coreutils/blob/master/src/ls.c#L4206

I am looking into what modifications are required if I want the files `README_string` where `string` is any kind of string to be colorified by the command "`l`" with the following alias in `~/.zshrc` :

```
alias l='grc -es --colour=auto ls --color -Gh -C -lrt'
```

How can I carry out this recompilation?

### Edit

Below the part of the code that manages the colorifying of file (https://github.com/wertarbyte/coreutils/blob/master/src/ls.c#L4206 ):

```
/* Check the file's suffix only if still classified as C_FILE.  */
  ext = NULL;
  if (type == C_FILE)
    {
      /* Test if NAME has a recognized suffix.  */

      len = strlen (name);
      name += len;      /* Pointer to final \0.  */
      for (ext = color_ext_list; ext != NULL; ext = ext->next)
        {
          if (ext->ext.len <= len
              && strncmp (name - ext->ext.len, ext->ext.string,
                          ext->ext.len) == 0)
            break;
        }
    }
```

I would like the file without extension to be colorified. I have some notions of C language but not enough to understand what happens in this section of the code.

What modifications could I apply for getting colorifying without extension ?

Comment: Have you tried `exa`? ( https://the.exa.website/ ). It supports glob patterns in LS_COLORS, and by default has some highlighting of README files.

Comment: @Gairfowl I tried it but an interesting functionality seems to not exist : the colorization as a function of size wen I do an `exa -l` . Moreover, I have to modified all my LS_COLOR since rendering colors are not the same with `exa` compared to `ls`.

Comment: @youpilat13 : Just being curious:  You try to avoid the - admittedly tedious - task to rewrite your LS_COLOR settings for `exa`, but you want to go through all the hassels to recompile `ls` instead, which, including testing your changes and not getting updates for `ls` anymore, which in overall will likely cost you much more effort in the end?

Comment: @user1934428 . Don't worry, I have nothing against `exa` but this is a little bit tricky since I don't use only LS_CLORS : I am using another layer with `grc` command (`grc -es --colour=auto ls --color -Gh -C -lrt` and this is the combination of the two that makes the rendering, not just LS_COLORS. That's why I would like to modify slightly the behavior of `ls`for files begining by README* and without extension separated by a point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grc` to colorize the README files in addition to what it's doing
now.  Since you have already set up the alias, just add a regex/color pair to a
copy of the `grc` config file for `ls`:

```
mkdir ~/.grc/
{
cat /usr/local/share/grc/conf.ls
cat << here
-
# README
regexp=(README[^.]*$)
colours=white on_blue blink
here
} > ~/.grc/conf.ls
```

---

If you still want to try changing the source for `ls`, you'll need several
modifications. Based on the source in your link, it looks like you need to ...

Change line 551 to:

```
    C_CLR_TO_EOL, C_README
```

Add this after line 593:

```
    { LEN_STR_PAIR ("37;44") },
```

Change line 4231 (`return false;`) to this:

```
    {
      if (startsWith(name, "README"))
        {
          if (is_colored (C_NORM))
            restore_default_color ();
          put_indicator (&color_indicator[C_LEFT]);
          put_indicator (&color_indicator[C_README]);
          put_indicator (&color_indicator[C_RIGHT]);
          return true;
        }
      else
        return false;
    }
```

And add this function somewhere before the `print_color_indicator` function:

```
bool startsWith(const char *pre, const char *str)
  {
    size_t lenpre = strlen(pre), lenstr = strlen(str);
    return lenstr < lenpre ? false : memcmp(pre, str, lenpre) == 0;
  }
```

All of this `C` code is completely untested (and my `C` is very rusty). It's also
not recommended - as noted in the comments, this will be difficult to implement
and to support.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! `grc` was the solution : why doing complicated instead of simple ? Best regards